# Why would using Ctype() to convert a SQL Server `int` to a .NET `Integer` raise an arithmetic error by calling ToShort()?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have this code:

```vb
If Not FieldRow.IsNull(Constants.conFieldEntityStoredProcedureID) Then
   EntityStoredProcedureID = CType(FieldRow(Constants.conFieldEntityStoredProcedureID), Integer)
End If
```

We are trying to convert a database value which is an `int` to an `Integer` but for some reason I get this stack trace:

> System.OverflowException Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
> EditEntityHandler at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToShort(Object Value)

Why would converting an `int` to an `Integer` involve calling ToShort()?

I confirmed that the database column where the value comes from only stores `int` values. I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot this. It's only happening on our production system for some reason.

Comment: You don't need CType. ADO.Net is already returning the correct value. A `DirectCast()` would be faster and likely bypass this error. The exception is if the value is stored in the database as a `binary(4)` instead of a real int, in which case things like little vs big endian byte order issues might come into play.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn plus I remember that VB.NET types are quirky, in an attempt to match VB6 types to .NET types.  Or `EntityStoredProcedureID` is a `short` ? The snippet of the exception shows that the error occured in `EditEntityHandler`, which I assume is the OP's method.

Comment: If the error is really in the `CType()` function then we can reproduce this error in a one-line example with no sql involved. So, can you debug and see an example value of `FieldRow(Constants.conFieldEntityStoredProcedureID)` when the error is thrown?

Comment: What is `EntityStoredProcedureID`? How was it defined?

Comment: I think you should use IsDBNull instead of IsNull.  JMHO

Comment: What does `FieldRow()` return? Do `Dim o = FieldRow(Constants.conFieldEntityStoredProcedureID)`, break after that line, inspect `o` for its type / underlying type if boxed.

Comment: @djv As the problem is only occurring on production instead of our development environment, I don't think I have a way to run the debugger while reproducing the error.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll The error is raised whenever we pass a value outside of Integer range.

Comment: *The error is raised whenever we pass a value outside of Integer range* ?? Then this would be the expected error, would it not?

Comment: @Wes Is the value of `Constants.conFieldEntityStoredProcedureID` what you think it should be?

Comment: @topsail I was a bit unclear on the question, I was just giving an example of when it is expected to raise the error that I'm seeing.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It appears to be, but even if it wasn't, I can't make sense of why using `Ctype(some_variable, Integer)` (which, as I understand, converts some_variable into an Integer) would have the compiler make a call to `ToShort()` along the way?

Comment: @Wasim If you split the line into individual parts just for the purpose of debugging, you'll be able to find exactly which step goes wrong. So, `var x = Constants.conFieldEntityStoredProcedureID;` `var y = FieldRow(x);` `var z = CType(y, integer);` `EntityStoredProcedureID = z;`. But change the `var` to explicit declarations.